# Show that it is false that $a > b$ implies $a\nmid b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that it is **false** that $a > b$ implies $a\nmid b$.

My try: If $a > b$ then $ a=b+c$ and $\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}=1 \Rightarrow $ both numbers on left hand side are non integers, hence $a$ does not divide $b$.

So the statement is TRUE but we have to prove it FALSE.

Dudley Page $8$, problem $5$.

Comment: $2 \mid -4$, or $23 \mid 0$.

Comment: What if b is zero? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication $a > b \implies a \nmid b$ is true if $a$ and $b$ are restricted to be strictly positive integers. This is the case you thought of, apparently.

But if we're looking at all integers, or even at the nonnegative integers, the implication is false. Since every integer divides $0$ - we have $0 = 0\cdot a$ for all $a$ - we have an infinite number of counterexamples $a > 0 = b$. If we consider all integers, then we also have counterexamples where $a > 0 > b$, like $2 \mid (-4)$.